# calculating student/class average with python

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.3

python 3.3.3

I am trying to write a program for class and I am lost. Here is what I need to do.

I need to calculate an average per student based on grades entered.
I need to calculate a class average.
if a student enters a grade of -1 input of grades stop.
need to print a message with each students grade.
the students grade should show a numeric grade and a letter grade.
the message will be based off of the students letter grade.

*how do i collect and store students name and test grades.
so that i can output it all at once to where it will show the students name.
thier numeric average, a letter grade based off that average, 
and a statement based off the letter grade they recieved*?

**heres the code i have so far:**

```
def main():
    another_student = 'y'
    while another_student == 'y' or another_student == 'Y':
        student_average()
        print()
        another_student = input('do you have another student to enter (y/n) ? ')
    while another_student == 'n' or another_student == 'N':
        student_average_list()
        class_average()
        break

def student_average():
    total = 0.0
    print()
    student_name = input('what is the students name? ')
    print()
    print()
    print(student_name)
    print('-------------------')
    number_of_tests = int(input('please enter the number of tests : '))
    for test_num in range(number_of_tests):
        print('test number', test_num + 1, end='')
        score = float(input(': '))
        total += score
    student_average = total / number_of_tests
    print ()
    print(student_name,"'s average is : ",student_average, sep='')

def student_average_list():
    print ('kahdjskh')

def class_average():
    print ('alsjd')

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is close to what you're basically looking for. It defines a`Student`class to make data storage and processing a little easier to manage.

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name, self.grades = name, []

    def append_grade(self, grade):
        self.grades.append(grade)

    def average(self):
        return sum(self.grades) / len(self.grades)

    def letter_grade(self):
        average = self.average()
        for value, grade in (90, "A"), (80, "B"), (70, "C"), (60, "D"):
            if average >= value:
                return grade
        else:
            return "F"

def main():
    print()
    print('Collecting class student information')
    a_class = []  # "class" by itself is a reserved word in Python, avoid using
    while True:
        print()
        print('{} students in class so far'.format(len(a_class)))
        another_student = input('Do you have another student to enter (y/n) ? ')
        if another_student[0].lower() != 'y':
            break
        print()
        student_name = input('What is the student\'s name? ')
        a_class.append(Student(student_name))
        print()
        print('student :', student_name)
        print('-------------------')
        number_of_tests = int(input('Please enter the number of tests : '))
        for test_num in range(1, number_of_tests+1):
            print('test number {}'.format(test_num), end='')
            score = float(input(' : '))
            if score < 0:  # stop early?
                break
            a_class[-1].append_grade(score) # append to last student added

    print_report(a_class)

def print_report(a_class):
    print()
    print('Class Report')
    print()
    for student in sorted(a_class, key=lambda s: s.name):
        print('student: {:20s} average test score: {:3.2f}  grade: {}'.format(
            student.name, student.average(), student.letter_grade()))
    print()
    print('The class average is {:.2f}'.format(class_average(a_class)))

def class_average(a_class):
    return sum(student.average() for student in a_class) / len(a_class)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a list of marks for the whole class. `student_average` function is doing too many things. Maybe make a function `get_student_marks` that just returns the list of a student's marks. You'd need an `average` function to compute the average of a list, which you could use for both student average and class average. Good luck!